# How to Show a Image on a flatlist in react native

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building an application in react native.I want to show some images in a flat box .How to Show a Image  on a flatlist in react native
[Here is my code](https://snack.expo.io/@savadks1818/react-native-flatlist-grid)

Comment: Have it render an `<Image/>` for every row? Please add your code for more detailed advice

Comment: @Kali here is my code ;- https://snack.expo.io/@savadks1818/react-native-flatlist-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React Native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html):

> Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!

Like this:

```
<Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'http://sslweb.solidstatelogic.com.s3.amazonaws.com/user-icon.png'}}
    />
```